# Hibernate HQL unexpected token with Likes

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

and I have this method in 1 DAO

```
final StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("  select app from Application app where upper (ticket_id) like :searchString and upper (id) like :searchString " );

        queryString.append("where  app.status != " + Status.READY.ordinal());

        queryString.append(" order by app.submissionTime desc ");

        try {

            final Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString.toString());

            searchString = searchString.replace("!", "!!")
                       .replace("%", "!%")
                       .replace("_", "!_")
                       .replace("[", "![")
                       .trim()
                       .toUpperCase();


            query.setParameter ("searchString", searchString);                      

            return query.getResultList();
```

But I have this error on runtime:

```
 org.   where near line 1, column 144 [  select app from com.tdk.devices.domain.Application app where upper (ticket_id) like :searchString and upper (id) like :searchString where  app.status != 0 order by app.submissionTime desc ]
```

Comment: column 144 is the start of app.status - nothing to do with likes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used "where" clause 2 times. First in the constructor of StringBuilder, then:

```
queryString.append("where  app.status != " + Status.READY.ordinal());
```